# Parse Json, found dic instead Array

Tags: swift, urlsession

i am trying to parse JSON, but here is a problem:
KeyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil) ("id").", underlyingError: nil))

Model:

```
struct CarResponse: Codable {
   let result: Int
   let data: [Car]
}

struct Car: Codable {
    let id: String
    let brandName: String
    let founderNames: [String]
    let foundationDate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case brandName = "brand_name"
        case founderNames = "founder_names"
        case foundationDate = "foundationDate"
    }
}
```

Method

```
protocol NetworkServiceProtocol {
    func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Result<CarResponse?, Error>) -> Void)
}

class NetworkService: NetworkServiceProtocol {

    func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Result<CarResponse?, Error>) -> Void) {
        let urlString = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db9630530000095005ee272"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else  { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(CarResponse.self, from: data)
                print(obj)
                completion(.success(obj))
            } catch {
                print(String(describing: error))
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db959e43000005a005ee206 - JSON

Comment: Your JSON response is a dictionary and the array that you're looking for is inside 'data' key. You should first read it as dictionary then get the value for 'data', then decode it as [Car].self

Answer (score 0):

add a this struct to you model

```
struct CarResponse: Coddle {
   let result: Int
   let data: [Car]
}
```

and change your decode function like this

```
guard let data = data else {
   completion(.failure(ACustomError))
   return
} 
let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(CarResponse.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I did it, but i still can not see JSON and app crashes

Comment: where is crashing. is the json response is the one in the link then the response is that

Comment: The reason is i got nil for every element of json... hmmm, btw thank you!

Comment: `{
    "number": "138",
    "language": "en",
    "insult": "Out of 100,000 sperm, you were the fastest?",
    "created": "2022-06-09 22:24:54",
    "shown": "109893",
    "createdby": "",
    "active": "1",
    "comment": ""
}`
this is not a json from http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db959e43000005a005ee206 this json is from the link in your code you need to check the url you are downloading a json

Comment: ah sorry, i just tested something... So now i use right JSON, and still get nil everywhere

Comment: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: you need to update you code with the changes you are making to understand

Comment: sure, updated..

Comment: your updated model is not match for the new url the new url have "brand_id" indented of ID, also in the link with example founder_names is an array of string [String] no a string use json4swift.com or appquicktype.io to generate the model according to the json with the valid url.